# How to add dependencies to workspace.dependencies using `cargo add`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is it possible to instruct cargo to add a dependency to a **workspace** manifest?

My repo is composed of a workspace w/ multiple packages. It looks something like

```
Cargo.lock
Cargo.toml
package_1/
  Cargo.toml
  src/
package_2/
  Cargo.toml
  ...
package_3/
  Cargo.toml
  ...
...
```

The parent `Cargo.toml` is specified as a workspace.

```
[workspace.package]
...

[workspace]
members = [...]

[workspace.dependencies]
some_package = "1.0"
...
```

And the `Cargo.toml`'s of each package refers to dependencies like so:

```
[dependencies]
some_package = { workspace = true }
...
```

When I run `cargo add <PACKAGE>` I get

> `cargo add` could not determine which package to modify. Use the `--package` option to specify a package.

Is it possible to instruct cargo to add a dependency to the workspace manifest? Ideally I could specify which package(s) to add the dependency to as well.

Otherwise, adding a dependency to a package is a manual process.

Answer (score 8):

There is currently no command-line argument to add a workspace dependency nor set a package to use that workspace dependency. So you will have to add it manually.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10608) that requests this feature.